# Why the interest in embedding and recursion?

Tags: discussion, questions

Is there a reason that there is an (over)abundance of questions about recursion and/or embedding? In my linguistics classes we never spent very much time on these issues, and I wasn't aware that many people were doing a lot of research on them. Yet, there are far more questions regarding these topics than I was expecting to encounter.

Has anybody else noticed this or hypothesized as to why this is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you noticed, all of these questions (or the 99% of them, not sure) have been asked by a single user. If that user is interested in that, then we can expect most questions will be asked on that topic.

There is not a problem in questions being heavily asked about that, unless this trend starts to be really obsessive about a certain topic, but we're *very far* from that situation, so no need to worry at all. :)

You can do something to mitigate this trend though: ask many questions about other topics yourself or invite your colleagues/professors/enthusiast friends to join our site! :)

Comment: You are correct, I did not notice they were all being asked by the same few people. I typically visit the site at night on the iPad, which is smaller than a normal screen, before I go to bed. :)

Comment: Keep visiting! :) And invite others, we don't mind more questions... :D

Answer (score 1):

A similar but more general concern has been raised by other users: that most questions and answers posted so far are too much focused on frameworks, theoretical models and... Chomskyan linguistics. This would be opposed to the more traditional approach, based on collecting massive data from a single language (or a single family) in order to get a deep understanding of it, irrespective of frameworks.

Honestly, I'm not in a position to judge it, but they may be on to something here. Of course, as Alenanno observed, we're to far from an obsessive situation. In any case, I would very much like to see more questions based on traditional linguistics!